# SQL Command to convert YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql, datetime, datetime-format, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am facing an operand type clash error due to this issue (in Pre-SQL Informatica) that says the date is incompatible with int, even though the date in target table is defined as datetime. How can I convert the existing YYYYMMDD date to YYYY-MM-DD format for my query?

Comment: use **DATE(COLUMN_NAME)** function

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this:

```
to_char(to_date(your_date, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

or

```
TO_DATE(your_date as String, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Yup, the issue turned out to be at mapping level, wherein I had not applied a TO_DATE to my string date value. Once updated, the workflow succeeded. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this function also it will work.

1) v_ port---date/time  TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(COLUMN_NAME),'YYYYMMDD')
 2) o_port----string TO_CHAR(v_ port,'YYYY-MM-DD')